# can't click bake button

Tags: unity-game-engine, navmesh

I am trying to make a NavMesh in Unity.
So when I look up any of the tutorials, they show / tell that you can simply make a plane for example navigation static, and then go to window -> AI -> navigation and click the bake button.

However, both the bake as well as the clear button stay grey and they are not clickable at all.
I cannot find an answer, so if anybody got an idea, ill be very gratefull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always make sure you are not in play mode!!